# Having $line arguments passed to rsync when using --protect-args option

Tags: shell-script, rsync

I have a script and this block of code -

```
cat file_list.txt | while read line
do
rsync --dry-run -avzPs '$line' '123.456.122.111:$line'
done
```

The file_list.txt looks like this -

```
/some/random/directory/file_name.txt
/some/other/directory/a file name.html
.....
```

The issue I have is that the rsync command will not work with the `$line` argument, due to how `--protect-args` works.  I need to have this option inside of the command because some of the filenames have spaces in them.

However, I can't just use a wildcard and pass everything since the text document contains all of the paths and specific files I want to pass.  How can I solve this?

Comment: you can specify `a\ file\ name` for space.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `--files-from=` to specify the files?

```
rsync -avzP --files-from=file_list.txt 123.456.122.111:
```

You could also add `--no-relative` if you want all the files in the same directory without the full path.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use single quotes enclosing variable names. Single-quoted strings are not evaluated.

Your script should be:

```
cat file_list.txt | while read line
do
    rsync --dry-run -avzPs "$line" "123.456.122.111:$line"
done
```